# Extrar un id del DataFrame con sus correspondientes filas

Tags: pandas, id

Tengo un `DataFrame` con **16 columnas** y **60 mil filas**. Al hacer el EDA observo que un solo `id` tiene **4300 registros**. Cómo puedo extraer ese `id` con sus 4300 filas?
Estas son las columnas

```
id                                    
name                                 
car_id                               
car_name
route_group                   
area                         
latitude                              
longitude                             
car_type                             
price                                 
minimum_travel                        
number_of_reviews                     
last_review                       
reviews_per_month                 
calculated_listings_count        
availability_365
```

En estas data un `car_id` tiene **4300 entradas** pero la data tiene **60 mil filas**. Deseo ubicar y separar el `car_id` especifico asociado con el `car_name` para analizar la informacion y proponer posibles conclusiones

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo bien tu pegunta. Interpreto que tiene un DataFrame con una forma parecida a este que denomino 'all_data', y cuyo principio puedes ver en esta imágen.

[image: Cabecera del DataFrame]

Este DataFrame, tiene tambien otros símbolos `simbolos = ['GE', 'JPM', 'MSFT', 'PG']` que lógicamente no aparecen en esta cabecera.

Para recuperar el DataFrame de cualquiera de estos símbolos, podemos hacer.

```
all_data.loc['GE']
```

que nos devolverá el DataFrame de 'GE
, en este caso, con todas sus líneas.

[image: DataFrame filtrado]

Quizás te ayude lo siguiente. en el DataFrame de mi ejemplo anterior, reseteo el índice 'symbols', para simular lo que podría ser tu DataFrame.

```
df = all_data.reset_index('symbols').copy(deep=True)
```

[image: DataFrame del ejemplo]

A continuación creamos un DataFrame  y filtramos los valores 'GE'
de la columna 'symbols'.

```
df_aux =  df[df['symbols'] == 'GE']
```

Nos devuelve este DataFrame

[image: DataFrame filtrado.]

La cuestión entonces es saber si tu conoces el valor de la columna 'car_id' de tu DataFrame que se encuentra en esas 4300 filas.

Estoy aprendiendo python; no soy un experto y seguramente hay alguna forma más sencilla.
Sería bueno que adjuntes un imágen de tu DataFrame., similar a las que yo he puesto en estos ejemplos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte efueyo. He ampliado la información en la pregunta con el objeto de ser mas especifico